# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x} \ln^{2} x \text{d}x$ without complex analysis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is possible to evaluate
$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x} \ln^{2} x \text{d}x$$
without using complex analysis?

Comment: @Axion004. Make an answer of it. It is to nice for staying in comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a long comment that has been turned into an answer. The approach applies known relationships between the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), and [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Using the fact that $$\int_0^\infty x^{a-1} \ e^{-bx} dx=\frac{\Gamma(a)}{b^{\ a}}\tag{1}$$

differentiate both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $a$ twice to get

$$\int_0^\infty (\ln x)^2\  x^{a-1} \ e^{-bx}\ dx=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Big(-2\psi(a)\ln b+(\psi(a))^2 +\psi'(a)+(\ln b)^2\Big)}{b^{\ a}}\tag{2}$$
 now set $a=1$ in $(2)$
$$\int_0^\infty (\ln x)^2\ e^{-bx}\ dx=\frac{2\gamma\ln b+\gamma^2 +\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}+(\ln b)^2}{b}$$

Finally set $b=1$ we get

$$\int_0^\infty (\ln x)^2\ e^{-x}\ dx=\gamma^2+\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

A similar approach was shown inside [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3311884/258202) in which it is shown that

$$\int_0^\infty \ln x\ e^{-x}\ dx=-\gamma$$

Comment: Thanks for making an answer and, for sure, $+1$